# Ubuntu partition with windows 10 "windows failed to start"

Tags: windows-10, boot-partition

Currently having a nightmare dealing with this. I installed ubuntu via usb  alongside windows 10 (upgraded from windows 8). When I select Windows 8 option in Grub get a:

"Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
1.insert windos cd and run a repair your computer option.
File: /boot/bcd
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data"

I can boot into ubuntu fine albeit wireless doesn't work. I enabled legacy support before install so I could boot from USB. I've tried booting from the usb I used to initially install ubuntu thinking maybe I could reinstall or repair, but it seems to ignore it. Is there some advanced startup options somewhere in ubuntu like there is in windows 10? Otherwise how will I run the Boot-Repair-Disk?

I know I should have done the research properly before doing this it's my own damn fault. Can somebody help in getting me out of this hole I put myself in?

Comment: Temporary workaround is to disable legacy support, and then you will be able to start windows.

Comment: Ubuntu is in BIOS mode and Windows in UEFI boot mode. You need to go into UEFI to change boot mode or use one time boot key. But many UEFI have a fast boot which is different from fast start up in Windows. You may not have time to press any key to get into UEFI. Sometimes cold boot, full power down, remove laptop battery, and hold power switch to drain power. Or even if BIOS, did grub add a System Setup boot option. It does for UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shutdown your machine. Then power it on while repeatedly pressing the function key appropriate for your machine to bring the bios screen. For Lenovo it is F2, for HP it is F12. Go to boot option. Move to windows using arrow keys. Use F6 to bring it to top. Use F10 to save and exit. Now the machine should boot fine.

If it doesn't then you can enter your windows CD, go to BIOS, then boot option. Here you will see an entry for Windows CD. Move it to top, save and exit. You can now repair your windows without any problem. Hope it helps.